# How to make my iOS radio app more efficient

Tags: ios, xcode, streaming, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm building an iOS radio app using AVPlayer that streams from a live url. How can I make it more energy efficient? I noticed that it is constantly making network calls and is at the top of my battery drain apps.

Comment: You can use the time profiler instrument and the energy monitoring instrument to examine your app, but this sort of app pretty much has to keep the radios powered up in order to transfer the stream of data.  There probably isn't much you can do.

Comment: There is not enough information to debug the situation for you.  To echo @Paulw11's comments though, there probably isn't anything you can do about it, assuming you're playing live content.  (How do you expect to play live content if you can't make the network requests to get that live content?)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information; I guess I was mostly wondering about the livestream URL. I noticed that the Apple Podcasts app uses very little energy; is that because it is mostly downloaded content, not live-streamed?

Answer (score 0):

Network calling will continue to drain your battery, but it's possible if you allow for the user to play the content in the background while their phone is locked it could stop as much draining- it will depend on the phone as well.